# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\log{k})^{e^{-k^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I am right if I consider that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\log{k})^{e^{-k^2}}$ is divergent since it is a positive term series with $\lim_{k\to\infty}(\log{k})^{e^{-k^2}}=1\neq 0$ so the necessary condition is not satisfied?

My idea for the limit is: $\lim_{k\to\infty}(\log{k})^{e^{-k^2}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}e^{\frac{\log{(\log{k})}}{e^{k^{2}}}}=1$ it is $1$ since the exponet goes to $0$ since the exponential goes to $\infty$ faster than logarithm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If that limit is correct, then yes.</strike>

You are correct. The terms $(\log k)^{e^{-k^2}}$ of the sum approach $1$ as $k\to\infty$, so the series is divergent.

For a homework or test problem, it would be pretty important to show how you concluded that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} (\log k)^{e^{-k^2}} = 1$. Note that this is a so-called "indeterminate form" $\infty^0$.

Comment: mmm do you mean that you are not sure that the limit is $1$?

Comment: You seemed to be asking whether your reasoning was correct, not whether the limit was correct. I didn't compute the limit.

Comment: Yes but I thought it was implied that my question required an overall checking. Can you check all the attempt?

Comment: The limit is 1, but how you got there is most important.

Comment: The limit is indeed 1. The attempt is correct

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question with the attempt on limit. Am I right?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Yes, it's good enough to convince me

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I guessed (without proof) the terms $\to 1,$ I decided to try to prove the terms were $> k^{-1}$ for large $k.$ Note that this proves divergence since $\sum k^{-1}=\infty.$

Applying $\log,$ this is the same as showing

$$e^{-k^2}\ln(\ln k) > - \ln k.$$

We're done, since for large $k$ the left side is positive and the right side is negative.